# Difference between VK_KHR_fragment_shading_rate and VK_EXT_fragment_density_map

Tags: vulkan

The attachment method of `VK_KHR_fragment_shading_rate` (FSR) extension seems to be similar to `VK_EXT_fragment_density_map` (FDM) extension.

One of the differences is in the way shading rate is defined. In FSR, fragment size is encoded directly in the texel value using bitwise operations whereas in FDM a density value (0-255) is provided and the implementation converts that into a fragment size. Are there any other differences? From an application developer's point of view, are they functionally the same?

There seems to be some discussion [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Guide/issues/70) but no definite answer.